# Probability of a blood test

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

It is known that a proportion p of patients admitted to a hospital presenting certain
symptoms suffer from a certain disease. The final diagnosis of it depends on an analysis of
blood. However, as individual tests are expensive, the hematologist waits until n patients
presenting symptoms visit him. He then he mixes the blood of the n patients and does the analysis. Yes
none of the n people is sick, the analysis on the sample of the blood mixture is negative.
On the other hand, if any of the patients are ill, then the test will be positive, and the hematologist
should perform individual tests on all individuals to determine which of the patients have the
disease.

a) Find the probability that the mixed blood test will be negative.

b) Determine the point probability function of the number of analyzes to be carried out by the hematologist
on the n patients.

c) Is it really convenient to use the method to analyze the hematologist's samples in relation to
be willing to perform an analysis on each of the patients if what is sought is to minimize the costs?

In part a) it would be to calculate the probability that each patient is not infected and multiply these probabilities since they are independent, but which would be this $( \frac {p}{n})^n$, $( \frac {1}{p})^n$ or $p^n$

and with the rest I am somewhat lost

Comment: Suppose that you have $n$ independent events, each of which has probability $p$ of succeeding, where $0 < p < 1$.  Let $q = (1 - p)$.  Then, the probability of a specific event failing is $(q)$.  What is the probability of $n$ independent events all failing?

Comment: For part (b), the presumption is that the number of tests performed on $n$ patients will be either $(1)$ or $(n + 1)$, depending on whether the initial combined test on all of the patients showed the disease.

Comment: For part (c), the presumption is that you have to determine the expected number of tests, as a function of $(q)$, and then determine for which value of $(q)$, the expected number of tests is equal to $n$ tests, which would be the number of tests if the initial combined test was bypassed, and each individual person was automatically tested.